# Copy columnwidth from workbook x sheet i to workbook y sheet i

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the column widths of my master workbook into a target workbook.
Everything else I've got to work like sheet protection, exception ranges etc. (note I apply sheet protection at the very END of the module)

I've tried several approaches both going column for column or an entire row or other ranges but it will do anything but copy the column widths.

```
 For col = 1 To col = Input_Obj_WS.Range("A1:XX1").Columns.Count
    With Output_Obj_WS.Columns(col)
        .ColumnWidth = Output_Obj_WS.Columns(col).ColumnWidth
    End With
 Next col
```

I got all kinds of errors but on my initial tries I got "Paste special of range class failed"

Right now I'm not getting errors anymore but it's just not doing anything.

Comment: shouldn't the starting line of loop be For col = 1 to  Input_Obj_WS.Range("A1:XX1").Columns.Count ?  (i.e. why For col = 1 to Col =)

Comment: GOod point, I'll try again. (I'm amazingly sleep deprived by now.)

Comment: Ok, I've adapted it but it's still not working. For some reason if I debug print this I only get the value 8.43. But I would expect lots of different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

So after some fiddling I've got it to work. I don't suppose this is the most elegant solution but it works for now.
@Bilal Thanks for the help

```
For Col = 1 To Input_Obj_WS.Range("A1:XX1").Columns.Count


    Debug.Print ("In: " & Input_Obj_WS.Columns(Col).ColumnWidth)
    Debug.Print ("Out: " & Output_Obj_WS.Columns(Col).ColumnWidth)

    Colwidth = Input_Obj_WS.Columns(Col).ColumnWidth
    Output_Obj_WS.Columns(Col).ColumnWidth = Colwidth


    Debug.Print ("Out 2: " & Output_Obj_WS.Columns(Col).ColumnWidth)


Next Col
```